# Is there an equivalent of set wildignore for ignoring files with nonprintable characters?

Tags: linux, vim

Currently I ignore certain file extensions, but I think it would be quite useful if I could have vim ignore binary files (where we might define binary as files with nonprintable characters) when doing tab completion.

I am running on Linux rather than windows, so just matching .exe is not useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no such setting, and I also don't see how it could be useful. Especially on Unix, many files with the executable bit set are actually scripts (Shell, Perl, Python, etc.), which are perfectly suitable for editing with Vim.

For custom `:command`s, you could build such a completion yourself (`-complete=custom` argument, using `executable()` for testing), but to apply this to built-in commands, you'd have to patch Vim's source code.

Comment: Suppose I am working in a directory with C files, Makefiles and binary files.

Comment: So your real requirement is **binary** files, not executables!

Comment: If it's really annoying to you, I would (if I could - I like this as a best practice, since it allows cross-compilation and multi-config) put the build artifacts into a subdirectory. Otherwise, you could explicitly add the binary file names to `'wildignore'` using one of the _local vimrc_ plugins found on vim.org.

Comment: Yes, I think binary files is more accurate. Let me edit that.